# @Version doesn't work with @DynamicInsert

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to let hibernate handle concurrency, and after some research the usage of @Version came out.
Below follows an example of what I'm doing so far:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    ID NUMBER NOT NULL
  , VERSION NUMBER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TABLE KEY (ID);

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicInsert;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Generated;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenerationTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_NAME", sequenceName = "SQ_MY_TABLE", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
public class MyTable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_NAME")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "VERSION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Version
    @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    private Long version;

    ... getters and setters
}
```

When my application tries to insert a new row into MY_TABLE, Oracle throws the exception

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MY_TABLE"."VERSION")
```

What am I missing? It works only if I remove @DynamicInsert...

PS: I'm using @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS) because if I don't use it I cannot perform 2 updates on the same record without requering it first.

Environment: JBoss EAP 6.3, java 1.7.0_79, hibernate 4.3.11.Final (using JTA), JSF 2.0 and Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I found out that when we use GenerationTime.ALWAYS or GenerationTime.INSERT we need to provide a database trigger to fill the field annotated with @Version.

In Oracle, for example, the trigger is something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_MY_TABLE_BIUR
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON MY_TABLE
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING THEN
        :NEW.VERSION := 0;
    ELSE
        :NEW.VERSION := :OLD.VERSION + 1;
    END IF;
END TRG_MY_TABLE_BIUR;
/
```